# android: placing bmp on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to draw a BMP on Canvas on the first touch of the screen but the problem is that the BMP keeps jumping everywhere I touch the screen. What I want is have the BMP stay fixed at the location of the first touch and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBarn, mTouchX, mTouchY, mPaint);
invalidate();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int eventAction = event.getAction();   

switch (eventAction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        mTouchX = (int)event.getX();
        mTouchY = (int)event.getY();                    
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
} 
invalidate();
return true;
```

}

Comment: Use a boolean value to tell you if you have touched the screen already. 
If the bolean is true, do nothing inside onTouch(). Otherwise, make tho touch Event and set your boolean to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
  package com.example.graphics1;


 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
MyBringBack ourView;
float x,y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourView = new MyBringBack(this);
    ourView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;
    setContentView(ourView);
}
    public class MyBringBack  extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
    {
        SurfaceHolder ourholder;
        Thread ourThread = null;
        boolean isrunning=true; 
        public MyBringBack(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            ourholder = getHolder();
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(isrunning)
            {
                if(!ourholder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas = ourholder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
                if(x!=0 && y!=0)
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap =  
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x-
        (bitmap.getWidth()/2), y-(bitmap.getHeight()/2), null);
                }
                ourholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x=arg1.getX();
    y=arg1.getY();      
    return true;
}

    }

Use this code this will help you..
```